# jQuery .hover only working on first li in my nav bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

In the following code I am using the id="nav-button" on hover to create a console.log so i can check if its working.

```
    <ul>                        <!-- Main Navigation -->
      <li ><a id="nav-button" href="welcome/about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li ><a id="nav-button" href="search-listings">SEARCH LISTINGS</a></li>
      <li ><a id="nav-button" href="featured">FEATURED</a></li>
      <li ><a id="nav-button" href="sell-your-home">SELL YOUR HOME</a></li>
      <li ><a id="nav-button" href="welcome/press">PRESS</a></li>
      <li ><a id="nav-button" href="welcome/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
```

My JavaScript looks like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#nav-button").hover(
        function(){
            console.log('done');
        });
});
```

For some reason only my first link responds to the on hover. The others don't do anything.

Comment: IDs must be unique in the document, you should be using classes instead.

Comment: The first link is the only one you're selecting. If you instead selected them all, they'd all have the hover event.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the very general rule of not using an ID more than once ?

Comment: damn i always for get that...ill be deleting this question sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't have more than 1 item with the same ID, they're not very unique if you do.  Change your HTML to:

```
<ul>                        <!-- Main Navigation -->
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="welcome/about">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="search-listings">SEARCH LISTINGS</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="featured">FEATURED</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="sell-your-home">SELL YOUR HOME</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="welcome/press">PRESS</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="welcome/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-button").hover(
        function(){
            console.log('done');
        });
});
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/UqyHD/

Answer (score 1):

ID is supposed to be unique, so you cannot have id="nav-button" appears more than once. What you could do is assigned id to the ul tag like below

```
<ul id="nav-buttons">                        <!-- Main Navigation -->
  <li ><a href="welcome/about">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li ><a href="search-listings">SEARCH LISTINGS</a></li>
  <li ><a href="featured">FEATURED</a></li>
  <li ><a href="sell-your-home">SELL YOUR HOME</a></li>
  <li ><a href="welcome/press">PRESS</a></li>
  <li ><a href="welcome/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

then, you may refers them as "#nav-buttons a"

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#nav-buttons a").hover(
        function(){
            console.log('done');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<ul>                       
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="welcome/about">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="search-listings">SEARCH LISTINGS</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="featured">FEATURED</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="sell-your-home">SELL YOUR HOME</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="welcome/press">PRESS</a></li>
  <li ><a class="nav-button" href="welcome/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a.nav-button").hover(
        function(){
            console.log('done');
        });
});
```

When you find an element by ID it will parse the DOM until it finds the first element with that ID. `$("a.nav-button")` will select all the elements with that class.